# fcc gov api call issue

Tags: php, api

i am retrieving data from fcc public api but i am facing some issues. data is coming but i need some more fields. but unable to find any solution.
this is api call and fields it returns

$url = 'https://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue='.$parameter.'&format=json&jsonCallback=""';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

it returns json object which is correct

```
stdClass Object ( [licName] => name [frn] => 123 [callsign] => abc [categoryDesc] => Personal Use [serviceDesc] => Vanity [statusDesc] => Active [expiredDate] => 03/26/2024 [licenseID] => 123 [licDetailURL] => url )
```

but i need some extra fields like

- Grant Date
- Effective Date
- Print Date
- file number ect.

i read api documentation but found nothing
any one can help me?

api documentation : https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/fccdomain/55a35f65-7efa-42af-98af-41ae37d824b2/license-view/

Comment: You need to give us a link to the documentation at the very least. Although,  its not really our job to read it for you, tbh.

Comment: The API doesn't do that.

Comment: https://www.fcc.gov/reports-research/developers/license-view-api

Comment: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/fccdomain/55a35f65-7efa-42af-98af-41ae37d824b2/license-view/